# Liszt - Hungarian Rhapsody No. 2 (Piano Solo) - Measure 306

Tags: technique, piano, rhapsody

In the picture below, there is a significant stretch where the melody in the upper staff is at a lower pitch than the accompaniment in the lower staff.

Does Liszt intend for me to cross my right-hand over my left?  Or am I meant to begin playing the upper staff with my left hand and the lower staff with my right?

If he means for me to cross over, is there a generally accepted preference between crossing my right hand over my left vs. under my left or vice-versa?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand it, this would be played by crossing your right hand over your left and playing the lower notes with your right hand.

In general, I think the hand that moves will be on top of the 'anchor' hand (the one that remains in position).

Comment: Ahh, this is how my hands naturally wanted to play it, so that's good.  Thanks for the input!!

Comment: Alternatively, he could have anticipated an evolution in humanity by now whereby you would have a third hand with which to play this section.  Food for though.